# Why are fringes displaced when a thin film is introduced (Michelson interferometer)?

Tags: optics, interference

I'm reading everywhere that when you place a thin film in one arm of an interferometer, fringes are displaced. No-one seems to explicitly say why; maybe because it's meant to be obvious. I know introducting the film changes the optical path length in one arm of the interferometer, but why does that have the specific effect of displacing the fringes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the zero order fringe where the two path lengths are equal.
If you introduce an extra number of wavelengths by adding the film in one path then the other path must be longer to produce the zero order fringe.